# Количество пар чисел от 1 до n что имеют общую цифру

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм, комбинаторика

У меня идея была такая,что найти все числа что имеют цифри 0..9, и формулой количества чисел count умножать на count-1, для подщета всех пар но увы не заходит :(

Подскажите любые хорошие варианты кроме решения "В лоб".

Пары могут быть (x,y) и (y,x) если x!=y и пара (x,y) если x==y.

```
Пример:
12
Вывод:
26 
Ограничения:

1<=n<=10^9

Час 2 секунды и память 256 Мб
```

Числа что имеют "1" - 1,10,11,12 - количество пар - 4*3 = 12

Числа что имеют "2" - 2,12 - количество пар - 2*1 = 2

И пары в которых x=y есть n - количество пар - 12

Сумма == 4*3+2*1+12 = 26.

Comment: Посчитать количество чисел xN в диапазоне от 1 до M, имеющих в составе хотя бы одну цифру N (задача тривиальная). Посчитать SUM(xN*xN-xN) + M. Всё.

Comment: @Akina не совсем тривиально. Одну пару несколько раз посчитаете. например 123 и 124 по 1 и по 2.

Comment: а какие ограничения на задачу? N не больше 100кк я надеюсь.

Comment: @pavel Гм... да, верно... если идти этим путём, получится "одиночки минус пары плюс тройки минус ..." - да, хреновато. Тады отбой.

Comment: @Akina лемма включений-исключений. ну её блин. Сейчас ответ напишу за O(n).

Comment: Какие ограничения на диапазон чисел?

Comment: Максимум что может быть то n=10^9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Код не пишу. Одно из решений содержит битовую маску вхождения цифр. Таких масок 1024 штуки (ладно 0 откинем, 1023).

Делаем массив до 1023.

Проходимся по числам. Увеличиваем счётчик нужной маски.

Потом двойной цикл по всем парам масок. Если у масок and побитовый не 0, значит нам подходит. К ответу произведение размеров.

Сложность O(n). Окей, O(n + 2^20).

Comment: Уточнение лишнее: O(n + 2^20) это то же самое, что O(n)

Comment: @dzhioev ну вообще да. Просто если N=1, миллион операций немного неожиданно. Поэтому и уточнил.

Comment: А если n=10^9? (

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets ну секунд за 5 успеть может. 100кк успевает за 1 секунду.

Comment: Ну а если там 2 секунды?еххххх......

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets тогда ускорять. Можно считать вхождение в каждую маску быстрее через комбинаторику. Например чтобы в числе из 4 знаков были только 1 и 2 есть 3 + 6 + 3 = 12 вариантов. Всего-то раза в 3 ускорить надо.

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets кстати, можно распараллелить код. Почти идеальные условия.

Comment: всм роспараллелить?Сорри не понимаю)

Comment: @AndriyOleksievets https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async вот например. Но опять же, это если вам такая задача нужна в реальной жизни. Если на олимпиаде то идею я написал, комбинаторика.

Comment: Мне ето чисто интересно подходы для решения,я свой обьяснил,и уже есть к чему стремится)Благодарю